# ngRepeat cant iterate through nested array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to access each value of my array of arrays:

```
[
 ["0","0","0"],
 ["1","1","1"],
 ["1","0","0"]
]
```

I've done only two ngRepeat inside

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="line in test">
  {{line}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="point in line">
        {{point}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It's probably something stupid, but I can't figure out.

here is plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/LeZw0HRab472dcNiHPQM?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is:

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="line in test">

        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="point in line track by $index">
            {{point}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/72a1Brmn2eBuTWhI8pfC?p=preview